Meaning of ように as Used in Songs
『夜に駆ける』 - YOASOBI

沈むように溶けてゆくように

『ビリーブ・イン・パラダイス』 - MAGIC PARTY

太陽が燃え尽き沈む、もう一度昇れるように

『Kaleidoscope』 - 茶太

手に入らぬからこそ、人は心を焦がす、心に刻むように

『恥ずかしいか、青春は』 - 緑黄色社会

ぶつけたところから熟れていく果実のように

This is probably an easy question to answer, but in many songs I hear, there is ように that trails off. I search online and nothing mentions this tendency in songs.
...Is this just "like"? Or it is a little more complicated?

[様]{よう}に can also be understood as "in order to".
At the end of an utterance, it can also be an expression of hope. The idea is that the omitted part of the sentence could just be お願いします - the speaker is making some silent prayer or request with the goal of some other thing happening - which pretty clearly communicates the desire for that thing to happen. (Or I guess it could be something more agentive, like 〇〇をする予定.)
In song lyrics it can be difficult to decide where the ends of sentences are intended to be, and thus whether these line-final ようにs are sentence-final. More context would be required to guess at that. (Common sense also applies. For example, it doesn't generally make sense for the speaker to wish to become depressed, or to "melt away" - but context could definitely justify that. I'm vaguely familiar with 夜に駆ける and it's a pretty depressing song, but I don't recall this lyric.) But otherwise I don't think there's any special interpretation of ように that's specific to song lyrics or other literary language.

Dang it, I will have to interpret in each situation. However, thank you for the response.

That's pretty much always necessary, honestly.

(especially when used with a noun + の) "for the sake of" <-- 「Noun+の+ように」が "for the sake of ～" の意味になるような例が思いつかないのですが。。。　どんな例がありえますか？　「Noun+の+ために」と勘違いされてません？

@chocolate 。。。あっ、そうです。エディットをしました。
